# how display the output from the shellStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developer a web application in asp.net .I use ssh.net to establish a connection between my application and the Cisco devices.
i use the below code:

1. to connect

   ```
       var ip = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
       var user = txtuser.Text;
       var passw = txtpass.Text;
       var connInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo(ip, 22, user, passw);
       var sshClient = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo);
       try
       {
           sshClient.Connect();
   ```
2. to run command i use 2 way:

   2.1.

   ```
           var cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("show user");

           Label1.Text = cmd.Result;
   ```

   its work fine withe router and switch but not working with firewall
   for that i try to use **shellStream** :

   2.2.

   ```
            var ss = this.shellStream;
            sshClient.Connect();
            this.shellStream = sshClient.CreateShellStream("dumb", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

            Console.WriteLine(SendCommand("enable", ss));

            Console.WriteLine(SendCommand(passw, ss));

            Console.WriteLine(SendCommand("show looging", ss));
   ```

i can send multiple command to divice but my probbleme is how to display the result of this command from the shellStream.
i try some thing like that but is not working

```
string reslt = Console.ReadLine();
Label1.Text = Reslt;
```

i try to mixed this 2 way like this

```
this.shellStream = sshClient.CreateShellStream("dumb", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

Console.WriteLine(SendCommand("enable", ss));

Console.WriteLine(SendCommand(passw, ss));

Renci.SshNet.SshCommand cmd;

cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("show logging");

txtenablepass.Text = cmd.Result;
```

but is not working and i have this Exception

> **Additional information: Failed to open a channel after 10 attempts.**

my question is how display the output from the shellStream ?

Comment: thx you Luizgrs  for  replay can you give me a example because im new in c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is old. But I hope this can still help someone.

```
var connInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("<IP>", 22, "<USER>", "<PWD>");
var sshClient = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo);

sshClient.Connect();
var stream = sshClient.CreateShellStream("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Send the command
stream.WriteLine("echo 'sample command output'");

// Read with a suitable timeout to avoid hanging
string line;
while((line = stream.ReadLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    // if a termination pattern is known, check it here and break to exit immediately
}
// ...
stream.Close();
// ...
sshClient.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found that works is to connect then make a read and write stream and use it to pass commands and read output, so:

`Renci.SshNet.SshClient client = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(server_name, username, password);
client.Connect();
Renci.SshNet.ShellStream stream = client.CreateShellStream("dumb",0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1000);`

Now that you have a stream opened you can write commands like:

`stream.Write(string command + "\n");`

or read it like this:

```
string temp_string = stream.Read();
```

Only problem is you need to time out for the duration of command before you read an output, I used empty "while" until expected string with my username was read and then broke out of it.

Comment: `stream.Read()` does not return a string.